# Read a 3x3 array from a text file into a 2d vector with correct format

Tags: c++

```
file.txt

13 14 15
10 17 152
1  34 56
```

---

```
string line;
ifstream infile("file.txt");
vector<vector<char> > num;

while (getline(infile, line)) {
    vector<char> row;

    for (char &c : line) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            row.push_back(c);
        }
    }
num.push_back(row);
}

for (vector<char> &row : num) {
    for (char &c : row) {
        cout << c << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I am new to C++ and i want some help on how to read the 3x3 array and store it into a 2d vector in the same format as the text file?
My current output looks like this:

```
1 3  1 4  1 5
1 0  1 7  1 5 2
1    3 4  5 6
```

Expected output:

```
13 14 15
10 17 152
1  34 56
```

Comment: HInt: What happens if you remove the `if (c != ' ')` and store all characters in the vector?

Comment: Do you want to store *characters*, or *numbers*?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Thanks. It worked when i removed that line

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i want to store int numbers but it only works with char. Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Assuming*** you really want to store the *numbers* from the file, not the characters, I recommend you put each line into an [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/basic_istringstream) and uses it to parse the numbers you would normally do from e.g. `std::cin` when you want to read plain `int` values.

Perhaps something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > num;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    int value;
    while (iss >> value)
    {
        values.push_back(value);
    }

    num.push_back(values);
}
```

With the input file as shown at the time of writing this answer, we should now have a 3x3 integer "matrix".

If we output it:

```
for (auto const& row : num)
{
    for (auto value : row)
    {
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

we should then get the output:

```
13 14 15
10 17 152
1 34 56
```

---

The inner `while` loop could be avoided if you use [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > num;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::vector<int> values(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss),
                            std::istream_iterator<int>());

    num.push_back(values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You're a legend

Answer (score 3):

It may help to change the way you are looking at the problem. Your use of `getline()` is fine, but when wanting to read multiple values from each line, you really need to think about it from the standpoint of what separates the values rather than the values themselves. It may be a spaces, as in this case, or a comma or a tab, etc... How you approach reading a delimited file is largely the same regardless of what the delimiters are.

Now in your case, having declared a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`, you were bitten by the fact that the default for reading type `char` is to read one-byte, e.g. one ASCII character, regardless whether that character is a `digit` or `alpha` character. Since you want to read numbers containing multiple digits, the choice of `char` as the type will cause the problem described above. Instead, choose a type that expects multiple digits, such as `int` for your read and you will avoid this problem.

Now, back to reading the delimited file. The general approach is to read each line with `getline()` and then create a `stringstream()` from the line from which you can read individual values using the normal iostream operator. By creating a `stringstream()` you ensure that you only read values present in the line and that eliminates the problem where `'\n'` is simply ignored as whitespace.

For example in your case, you can pass an open `std::ifstream` along with a reference to a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as parameters to a function, then read each line, create a `std::stringstream()` from the line, and then fill a temporary vector of `int` with the values from the `stringstream()`. When done reading values into the temporary vector, you simply add that vector to your collection of vectors. You could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool read_vv_int (std::ifstream& infile, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv)
{
    std::string line {};                        /* string to hold line */
    size_t szbegin = vv.size();                 /* save beginning size of vv */
    
    while (getline (infile, line)) {            /* read each line */
        std::stringstream ss {line};            /* create stringstream from line */
        std::vector<int> v {};                  /* create temp vector to fill */
        int i;                                  /* int to read from stringstream */
        
        while (ss >> i)                         /* while int read from stringstream */
            v.push_back(i);                     /* add to temp vector */
        
        vv.push_back(v);                        /* add temp vector to vector of vector */
    }
    
    return szbegin != vv.size();                /* return true if vectors added */
}
```

(**note:** the function type `bool` is used to indicate success or failure of adding to your vector. If the size of your collection after your attempt at adding is the same as it was to begin with -- nothing was added, and the function returns `false`)

In `main()` to read your values into your collection you would simply open the file, validate the file is open for reading, declare your `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and pass the open file stream along with a reference to your vector of vectors as parameters. On successful filling of your collection you can output them as follows:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    if (argc < 2) { /* validate argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient input\n"
                     "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv {};        /* create vector of vector int */
    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);              /* open file */
    
    if (!infile.good()) {   /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (read_vv_int (infile, vv))               /* if vectors successfully added */
        for (const auto& r : vv) {              /* loop over rows */
            for (const auto& c : r)             /* loop over cols */
                std::cout << " " << std::setw(3) << c;  /* output value */
            std::cout.put('\n');                /* tidy up with newline */
        }
}
```

(**note:** those are the two complete halves of the program which you can simply paste together and compile and test)

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in the file `dat/3x3.txt`, you could read the file and generate the following output:

```
$ ./bin/read_2D_from_file dat/3x3.txt
  13  14  15
  10  17 152
   1  34  56
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

print like this remove ' ' this

```
for (vector<char> &row : num) {
    for (char &c : row) {
        cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: it gives the output with no spaces

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
 while (getline(infile, line)) {
 vector<char> row;

 for (char &c : line) {
         row.push_back(c);
     }
  num.push_back(row);
 }

for (vector<char> &row : num) {
      for (char &c : row) {
         cout << c;
         if(c==' ')
             cout<<" ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: *Why* will this "work"? Please try to explain the problem and what you did to solve it. Please read or refresh [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)